# Ionic 3 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' after installing firebase dynamic links plugin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  >   Searched Location: 
  >   /home/yushin/Desktop/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
  >   /home/yushin/Desktop/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
  >   /home/yushin/Desktop/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/google-services.json
  >   /home/yushin/Desktop/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  >   /home/yushin/Desktop/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
  >   /home/yushin/Desktop/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/google-services.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this only required to and add the google-service.json file to the app/src/debug and the app/src/release folders

Comment: this only required to add the google-service.json file to the platform/android/app folders